# Why am I getting Python Django-autotranslate package installation problem on windows?

Tags: python, django, pip, pypi

I try to install Django autotranslate package but it gives error as "Encountered error while generating package metadata."

```
pip install django-autotranslate
```

ERROR :
Collecting django-autotranslate
Using cached django_autotranslate-1.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: six in d:\pps\venv\lib\site-packages (from django-autotranslate) (1.16.0)
Collecting polib
Using cached polib-1.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
Collecting goslate
Using cached goslate-1.5.4.tar.gz (14 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: django in d:\pps\venv\lib\site-packages (from django-autotranslate) (3.2.13)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse>=0.2.2 in d:\pps\venv\lib\site-packages (from django->django-autotranslate) (0.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in d:\pps\venv\lib\site-packages (from django->django-autotranslate) (2022.7)
Requirement already satisfied: asgiref<4,>=3.3.2 in d:\pps\venv\lib\site-packages (from django->django-autotranslate) (3.5.0)
Collecting futures
Using cached futures-3.0.5.tar.gz (25 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [25 lines of output]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 2, in 
File "", line 14, in 
File "D:\PPS\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools_*init*_.py", line 18, in 
from setuptools.dist import Distribution
File "D:\PPS\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 32, in 
from setuptools.extern.more_itertools import unique_everseen
File "", line 1027, in *find_and_load
File "", line 1006, in *find_and_load_unlocked
File "", line 674, in *load_unlocked
File "", line 571, in module_from_spec
File "D:\PPS\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\extern_*init**.py", line 52, in create_module
return self.load_module(spec.name)
File "D:\PPS\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\extern_*init**.py", line 37, in load_module
**import**(extant)
File "D:\PPS\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools_vendor\more_itertools_*init**.py", line 1, in 
from .more import *  # noqa
File "D:\PPS\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools_vendor\more_itertools\more.py", line 5, in 
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
File "C:\Users\Hope\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cit75cnm\futures_ec7c1d83d7964a80a1b0bce36c08edbc\concurrent\futures_*init*_.py", line
8, in 
from concurrent.futures._base import (FIRST_COMPLETED,
File "C:\Users\Hope\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-cit75cnm\futures_ec7c1d83d7964a80a1b0bce36c08edbc\concurrent\futures_base.py", line 357          raise type(self._exception), self._exception, self._traceback
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.

I downgraded pip package and tried to install. I did not understand with [this](https://github.com/ankitpopli1891/django-autotranslate/pull/26) what should I do.

Comment: Try another version for the module `futures`.

Comment: I tried till 0.8.0 versions. Unfortunaly it gives same error.